# Default Blur Text in inputField

Tags: visualforce

How to have a default value in the inputField in Visual Force in a blur format, For e.g. to enter a Number field : the value should be 'Enter a Number'.

As soon as the user clicks to enter the value in the inputField, it should not display anything.

Any advice.

Comment: :My initial thought is for this type of senario we wmay use Jquery plugin that can be more easier .Let me do some homework on this now.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out in both the ways : for html and apex vf tags. Please find below the code.

Jquery Plugin was the solution.

```
 <apex:includeScript value="http://digitalbush.com/files/jquery/watermarkinput/beta1/jquery.watermarkinput.js"/>
```

I used the above JQuery Plugin.

var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
  j$(document).ready(function(j$){
     j$('[id$=temp]').Watermark("Enter your Name");
  });

```
 <apex:inputText value="{!strTemp}" id="temp"/>
```

Comment: Perfect Buddy!!!Thanks for sharing might help us too.

Comment: No Problem Mohith. Cheers

Comment: Won't the actual id in the VF generated DOM element not actually be "temp"?  See http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm.

Comment: the id you set of 'temp' will be appended at the end of the Salesforce generated id.  the $= operator in jquery matches elements 'ending with' the value to the right.  http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/